# LAN7500 maximum transfer speed

Tags: integrated-circuit

What is the maximum transfer speed of USB 2.0 to Gigabit Ethernet bridge IC [LAN7500](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/lan7500). I ask since the maximum transfer speed of USB 2.0 is 480 Mbps, so how is it possible that the LAN7500 chip provides 1 Gbps Ethernet?

Answer (score 2):

> so how is it possible that the LAN7500 chip provides 1 Gbps Ethernet?

The chip's buffering system stores the received packets over gigabit ethernet network, converts and then transmits them over USB 2.0 to the host device. Similarly, it stores the incoming packets from the host over USB 2.0, converts and then transmits over gigabit ethernet network.

This is how the USB-side supports USB Hi-speed (2.0), and the eth-side supports gigabit ethernet.

Comment: Note that "supporting gigabit Ethernet" means "can send packets at 1Gb/s", but does **not** mean "supporting a **sustained** data transfer of 1 Gb/s"; as you say, it's only that fast for as long as the on-board buffer isn't full (receive direction) or empty (transmit direction).

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, that's true. My wording may lead to a misunderstanding. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I think your wording is fine; it's just that people that buy a product saying "gigabit ethernet" would be prone to have the preconception that it does 1 Gb/s, forever.

Comment: Not to mention, USB can't sustain 480 Mbps of payload traffic, either. Between the protocol overhead and other system issues, you're lucky to get about 80% of that, or 400 Mbps.